# How to read most recent item from IObservable from Func?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm writing a user interface. In some action, I want to know the most recent value from a particular IObservable. How can I learn that?

Here's a test simulating what I'm trying to achieve. Can you help fix it?

```
var selectedItemOut = new Subject<int?>();

// idea: define some other IObservable or subject here

var getLatest = new Func<int?>(() =>
{
    // fix me
    return 0;
});

Assert.AreEqual(null, getLatest());

selectedItemOut.OnNext(4);
Assert.AreEqual(4, getLatest());

selectedItemOut.OnNext(5);
Assert.AreEqual(5, getLatest());

selectedItemOut.OnNext(6);
selectedItemOut.OnNext(7);
Assert.AreEqual(7, getLatest());
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if there hasn't been a value published yet?

Comment: @CharlesNRice good question. Null, ideally.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This seems very backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change your selectedItemOut Subject to be BehaviorSubject like Slugart has that would be the best (I would change First() to Take(1), but that's just me).  If you cannot then you will need to create a variable outside the function scope.

```
var selectedItemOut = new Subject<int?>();

// Hold the last result from the OnNext
int? results = null;

// idea: define some other IObservable or subject here

// update var each time OnNext is called
var lastResult = selectedItemOut.Subscribe(i => results = i);

// just a wrapper around the results var.
var getLatest = new Func<int?>(() => results);
Assert.AreEqual(null, getLatest());

selectedItemOut.OnNext(4);
Assert.AreEqual(4, getLatest());

selectedItemOut.OnNext(5);
Assert.AreEqual(5, getLatest());

selectedItemOut.OnNext(6);
selectedItemOut.OnNext(7);
Assert.AreEqual(7, getLatest());

//Need to tell the observable to stop updating the results var.
lastResultDispose.Dispose();
```

Now really your func is just referencing the result var and you would need to tell it when to stop tracking it.  This isn't very Rx because Rx is about pushing values and you want to retrieve a value from it.

Answer (score 2):

If selectedItemOut can be a `BehaviourSubject<int?>`, you can use its `Value` property:

```
var selectedItemOut = new BehaviorSubject<int?>(null);

var getLatest = new Func<int?>(() =>
{
    return selectedItemOut.Value;
});
```

Otherwise CharlesNRice's answer looks fine, or you could use `MostRecent`:

```
var mostRecent = selectedItemOut.MostRecent(null).GetEnumerator();    
var getLatest = new Func<int?>(() =>
{
    mostRecent.MoveNext();
    return mostRecent.Current;
});

// need to clean up this up
mostRecent.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want an initial value (even if it's null) and then the most recent you could use a `BehaviorSubject` with `First()`.  A little more info on the context would help with a better solution as using `First()` is not recommended.

```
var selectedItemOut = new BehaviorSubject<int?>(null);

// idea: define some other IObservable or subject here
Assert.AreEqual(null, selectedItemOut.First());

selectedItemOut.OnNext(4);
Assert.AreEqual(4, selectedItemOut.First());

selectedItemOut.OnNext(5);
Assert.AreEqual(5, selectedItemOut.First());

selectedItemOut.OnNext(6);
selectedItemOut.OnNext(7);
Assert.AreEqual(7, selectedItemOut.First());
```